# My .net mvc Spark Views are not deployed on the server via MsDeploy (TFS 2010)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

I don't understand.. When I build/deploy my .net mvc project in TFS 2010, all my Spark View (.spark files) are not deployed (Buil/deploy is OK).

I have to configure something to deploy these views ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Build Action as `Content` for those files:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can check the link below if you are using Visual Studio 2010 so that the default BuildAction for spark files will be Content. This way, you won't have to change the Build Action everytime you add a spark view.

http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx

Comment: that's cool - I've been looking for exactly something like this for a different file type.  Although I also need it for VS2008; which I think is a pipedream.